# Facebook and google login in Identity.UI/3.1.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to do the social login in asp.net core 3.1 with `Identity.UI/3.1.8`, but keep getting an error as `Error loading external login information.`, I don't know whats going on inside the identity server.

How can I know what is wrong with the social login

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    
                    options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx";
                    options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx--xxxxxxx";
                }).AddFacebook(options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.AppId = "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx";
                    options.AppSecret = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx";
                });
```

[image]

I can see the error in the OnGetCallbackAsync() of the scaffold of identity

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the IdentityServer log says? I would put breakpoints in the ExternalLoginModel and ExternalController classes and see if I can pinpoint the reason.

Comment: @ToreNestenius I have now the scaffold code of the Identity, now I have the _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); as null.Do you have any idea what is the issue

Comment: What does Your startup class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Addding GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme and FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme works

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxx.xxx";
                    options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxx";
                }).AddFacebook(FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options =>
                {
                    options.AppId = "xxxxxxx";
                    options.AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxxx";
                });
```